# How to validate that at least one element in a html string has content?

Tags: java, html

I have a wysiwyg editor that I can't modify that sometimes returns `<p></p>` which obviously looks like an empty field to the person using the wysiwyg.

So I need to add some validation on my back-end which uses java.

should be rejected

```
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<div><p> </p></div>
```

should be accepted

```
<p>a</p>
<div><p>a</p></div>
<p> </p>
<div><p>a</p></div>
```

basically as long as any element contains some content we will accept it and save it.

I am looking for libraries that I should look at and ideas for how to approach it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to do it on the client side. The reason is because it is natural for the browser to do this. You need to hook your wysiwyg editor in the send or "save" part, a lot of them have this ability.

Javascript would be

```
function stripIfEmpty(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   var contentText = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
   if(contentText.trim().length === 0){
       return "";
   }else{
       return html;
   }
}
```

In the case if you need backend javascript, then the only correct solution would be to use some library that parse HTML, like jsoup - @Dmytro Pastovenskyi show you that.

If you want to use backend but allow it to be fuzzy, not strict, then you can use regex like `replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")` then trim, then check if the string is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You may look on [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. It's pretty fast

It takes HTML and you may return text from it (see example from their website below).

[Extract attributes, text, and HTML from elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (built-in to Java).

For example,

```
"<p>\\s*\\w+\\s*</p>"
```

would match a `<p>` tag with at least 1 character of content.

Comment: Thank-you this might be a better idea rather than pulling in an entire library.

Comment: I think so, and, you're welcome! You can also use it to sanitize the input - strip the empty tags rather than reject the entire document.